# Position: Fixed in Sidebar - How to stop it before footer?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery for floating widget in my sidebar - link to my post http://www.product-investigation.com/fat-loss-factor-review - if you scroll down, you can see what I mean ..I want to stop my adsense widget in sidebar before footer..thanks for help :)

My javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        function isScrolledTo(elem) {
            var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //num of pixels hidden above current screen
            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
            var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top; //num of pixels above the elem
            var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
            return ((elemTop <= docViewTop));
        }
        var catcher = $('#catcher');
        var sticky = $('#sticky');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if(isScrolledTo(sticky)) {
                sticky.css('position','fixed');
                sticky.css('top','100px');
            }
            var stopHeight = catcher.offset().top + catcher.height();
            if ( stopHeight > sticky.offset().top) {
                sticky.css('position','absolute');
                sticky.css('top',stopHeight);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `if(isScrolledTo(sticky))` inside an `else` statement? Somewhat like `if(stopHeight > sticky.offset().top){...}else{ if(isScrolledTo(sticky)){...} }`..

Comment: that doesnt work for me :(

Comment: Uh... can you setup [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? So that I can help you debug your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k56yR/90/

Comment: I've posted an answer. Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 3):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k56yR/91/). I changed something in your conditions:

```
return ((elemTop <= docViewTop || elemTop >= docViewTop)); //Changed your return in isScrolledTo
```

Explanation: The code that I added below will position the `sticky` div at the top of the `footer`, If I use your original `return` statement and scroll up, the `sticky` div's position will still be `absolute` on top of the `footer`. It's because your `return` statement will only check if the `top` position of the element is less or equal to the `scrollTop()` value, which can only be used during `scrolldown`. In my case where the `sticky` is already at the bottom part, the `isScrolledTo()` should also check if the `top` of the `sticky` div is greater or equal to the `scrollTop()` value.

and added some things in the `.scroll()`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledTo(sticky)) {
      sticky.css('position','fixed');
      sticky.css('top','2px');
    }
    var stopHeight = catcher.offset().top + catcher.height();
    var stickyFoot = sticky.offset().top + sticky.height();

    if(stickyFoot > footTop -10){ //Check if sticky's foot passes footer's top
      console.log("Top of Footer");
      sticky.css({
        position:'absolute',
        top: (footTop - 20) - sticky.height()
      });
    } else {
      if ( stopHeight > sticky.offset().top) {
        console.log("Default position");
        sticky.css('position','absolute');
        sticky.css('top',stopHeight);
      }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a great answer and works well, my only criticism (and it is really minor) is that you have two divs in your js fiddle with the same id "catcher" this would not be valid html, In my solution i changed it to a class and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't noticed that one haha